# height and width of background picture adapt to each screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, resolution, onload, screen-resolution

I've been working for some time on my first website. I have the CSS working but I still need to fix some simple, but no so simply issues. In the index.html file I have a background picture attached to the html. So I have a fullscreen background picture attached via CSS to the html tag. This is the CSS code:

```
html{   background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;     -moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;  -ms-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; }
```

But I'm loading the pictures via Javascript. My objective is to have an array of pictures and each time a user loads the website or triggers it a random picture will be displayed. So I have this code in Javascript which is working:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
  var randomImages = ['img1','img2','img3','img4','img5'];
   var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImages.length);
   $("html").css({
      background: "url(_img/bg/index_rnd/" + randomImages[rndNum] + ".jpg)
      no-repeat"
    });
});
```

All these codes are working. The pictures are selected from an array and displayed randomly once they are loaded. But I have a great problem which I cannot find a clear answer and I'm stuck. I would like that the **width and the height are rezised**, so the whole picture is displayed in the screen. Of course each screen is different... I read something about innerhieght and innerwidth properties, but I do not know how to proceed. What should I do so the pictures resize to each different screen?

In this moment the pictures are with a resolution of 1024x683. I have a computer with a screen of 15"" and a resolution of 1440x900. My pictures get always a bit more pixelated and to long in height to display, so a part of the picture is cut.

Questions:

What should I do so the pictures resize to each different screen resolution?

A recommended picture resolution so the picture is displayed correctly?

Is there a way to display the picture into the exact size of a screen? Even if its original format gets a bit modified?

REPLY AFTER RECIEVING ANSWER -------------------------------------------------------------
NEW QUESTION -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Hello, at last I had time to use the code... It does work properly. I only needed to add the url to my image folder and magic!!! So my code is actually like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var randomImages = ['img1','img2','img3','img4','img5'];
    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImages.length);

     var $win = $(this);
     var $img = $('#background').attr('src', '_img/bg/index_rnd/' + randomImages[rndNum] + '.jpg').css({'position':'fixed','top':0,'left':0});
        function resize() {
            if (($win.width() / $win.height()) < ($img.width() / $img.height())) {
              $img.css({'height':'100%','width':'auto'});
            } else {
              $img.css({'width':'100%','height':'auto'});
            }
        }
        $win.resize(function() { resize(); }).trigger('resize');
    });
```

Regarding my html I have for now an image with id background. I want to center the image as told. So my question is if I should put this image in a div. If so, how can I make this image center itself in the center of the screen???

Another question, before I had my image attachted to the html and now to an image. Therefore the image  is influencing other elements I have in my body. How can I make that this image be displayed behind all the other elements of my body?!?! For example my logo and header_bg are transformed when my img id="background" is loaded.

Can you help???

This is my html for any doubts...

```
<body>
        <img id="background" src="" alt="" />
        <div id="header_img">
            <nav>
                <div id="header-bg-left">
                    <div id="nav-content">
                        <div id="logo">
                                <a href="index.html"><img alt="./_img/nav/logo.rosa.png" src="">logo</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="categories">       
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="nav-quien"><a href="#">quien es</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li id="nav-biografia" class="drop1"><a href="biografia.html">biografia</a></li>
                                            <li id="nav-curriculum" class="drop2"><a href="curriculum.html">curriculum</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="nav-galeria" class="marginli"><a href="gallery.html">galeria</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li id="nav-gal-nat" class="drop3"><a href="gallery.html">paisaje natural</a></li>
                                            <li id="nav-gal-urb" class="drop4"><a href="gallery.html">paisaje urbano</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="nav-prensa" class="marginli"><a href="prensa.html">prensa</a></li>
                                    <li id="nav-links" class="marginli"><a href="links.html">links</a></li>
                                    <li id="nav-contacto" class="marginli"><a href="contacto.html">contacto</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <footer>    
            <div id="footer-bg-left">
                <div id="foot-content">
                    <p>Diseñado por <a href="mailto:daniramirezescudero@gmail.com">Daniel. R-Escudero</a> <span>|</span> Todos los derechos reservados <span>|</span> <a href="mailto:info@scalesplanet.com">info@rosasusaeta.com</a> <span>|</span><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/"><img src="./_img/footer/logo.linked.png"></a> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="./_img/footer/logo.facebook.png"></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: updated with working example: http://jsbin.com/oxetuy/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*UPDATED 29 Nov 2012*

> - **demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/height-and-width-of-background-picture-adapt-to-each-screen-size/

```
        $(window).resize(function() {
            resize();
        });
        $(function() {
            $('#background').attr('src', 'http://cdn.com/bg.png').css({
                'position' : 'fixed',
                'top' : 0,
                'left' : 0
            });
            resize();             
        });
        function resize() {
            var $img = $('#background');
            if (($(window).width() / $(window).height()) < ($img.width() / $img.height())) {
                $img.css({
                    'height' : '100%',
                    'width' : 'auto'
                });
            } else {
                $img.css({
                    'width' : 'auto',
                    'height' : $(window).height() + 'px'
                });
            }
        }

<body>
  <img id="background" src="" alt=""/>
</body>
```

Comment: The trick is, as posted, to find the ratio of window width:height and the ratio of image width:height. These are relatively simple numbers, but will tell you if the window is 'portrait/landscape' and the image is 'portrait/landscape' and the rest scales appropriately.

If the ratio for the window is less than the ratio for the image, then the height of the image should be the total height of the window, and the width is automatic.

If the opposite is true, it scales the image for width and height is automatic.

You may still need to centre the image within the div it is being displayed within.

Comment: Thanks, nosariuos and aSeptik. Im currently busy with other projects but I will apply this in my web this month. I will let you know... To centre the image within the html in this case what should I do exactly?!?! DO I need to insert it into a div?!?!?! Thank you

Comment: Nosarious and other users... Could you maybe help me with the new problem displayed above in my new edit?!?! The code works perfectly but I wan to know the best method to center the image and to display the "img" as background so it doesn't affect my other html code.

Comment: wrap your html (without the bg img) with a div like id="wrapper" and give to it via css the following properties: #wrapper { position:relative;z-index:2 } then give to the #background { z-index:1 } that's all.

Comment: Thank you Septik, that made it go into the background. Some things changed in my code, objects with absolute position changed completely. I will work that out... One question you can maybe answer. Will this work cross-browser properly?!?! Thank you!!

Comment: Since you now have the wrapper with position relative you have to change all absolute positions in relation to that wrapper and not to the body like you done before (this is why they changed completely). The answer is yes it is cross-browser. you can for example give to the #wrapper a width of 960px and center it with #wrapper { width:960px; margin: 0 auto; } and body { text-align:center } for /* IE5-6 */